# To accuse him of all people!

Tags: phrase-meaning

> To accuse him of all people!

I read the sentence above in an English book and can't understand the meaning of it. What does this sentence mean?

Comment: What book? What page? What was the context? Don't say there was no context, unless you mean there was a book with blank pages and just this phrase.  Was it an book in English, or an English textbook.  If it was a textbook, then what was the lesson in the textbook about?

Answer (score 2):

"of all people" means "out of all people" / "from among all the possible people that can be accused"

It means, to accuse him out of so many people, which seems to show that the speaker is suprised that he's been accused, because they don't think that he's capable of committing the crime he's been accused of.

Comment: This is correct, but doesn't make clear that _of all people_ used in this was is an idiom, expressing surprise or indignation.

Answer (score 2):

"of all people" phrase implies that this person has some characteristic that should exclude that person -- in this case from being accused.  Also implies that the speaker is surprised.

For example:  "Spud Webb -- of all people -- won the NBA Slam Dunk contest!"

Why is it amazing that Spud Webb would win?

- NBA = National Basketball Association
- Basketball is dominated by tall people -- 6 foot 6 inches and up.
- A basketball goal is 10 feet above the ground
- The Slam Dunk Contest is an annual event where the players "dunk" -- shove the basketball through the goal FROM ABOVE.
- Spud Webb is only 5 foot 7 inches tall.

It is very surprising that Spud Webb played in the NBA.  It is much more surprising that Spud Webb -- of all people --  would win the Slam Dunk contest.